# is there a way with tensorflow.js to input a shape with -1 as one of the shape value

Tags: javascript, arrays, numpy, matrix, tensorflow.js

In numpy, you can input a shape with a value of -1 which will do:

```
np.arange(9)
>>> array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])

np.arange(9).reshape((3,-1))
>>> array([[0,1,2],
           [3,4,5],
           [6,7,8]])
```

it will infer the remaining shape to have. (3,3) in this case.

but in tensorflow.js when I do:

```
const data = tf.tensor([0,0, 127, 255], [2,-1]);
```

it throws an error. Is there an equivalent to do this with tf.js?

Comment: Try `null` instead of `-1`. Not sure but could work

Comment: still throws an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have the same behavior with tensorflow.js when using [reshape](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.13.0/#reshape). But it does not work when creating the tensor. See the following:

```js
const x = tf.tensor1d([1, 2, 3, 4]);
x.reshape([2, -1]).print();
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.12.0"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: so apparently reshaping a tensor with -1 in the shape works but initializing it with -1 in the shape doesnt

Comment: @Tissuebox, yes that's it !